# Windows xp can't resolve unqualified name when connected by vpn

Tags: windows-xp, networking, vpn

I'm connecting to vpn using cisco vpn. The problem is, when I connect from win xp machine, i cant ping hosts using unqualified name. When I'm connecting to vpn network from my ubuntu machine, i can access hots on that network using unqualified names. So the problem I believe in windows network settings. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a DNS suffix. I would love to avoid linkrot, but let's face it: XP is a linkrot in itself. You can find instructions [here](http://support.simpledns.com/KB/a137/how-to-configure-dns-suffixes-on-windows-2000xp2003.aspx).

**Update**

For future visitors, right click your network connection=>Properties=>TCP/IP=>Properties=>Advanced=>DNS Tab

Comment: It's working, i've added domain name to "DNS suffix for this connection" field, and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @MDMoore313 - You could at the very least include the instructions without the screenshots.  Saying you "hate linkrot" but contribute to the problem is sort of funny.

Comment: @Ramhound I know, but I have such a disdain for XP now, mainly b/c it's a dying art. Neverless, I have conceded to your demands.

Comment: @MDMoore313 - I gave you an upvote just for your thoughts on Windows XP which I have had for almost a half decade.